# Run Python script from Node.js--Getting ImportError:no module named google.cloud

Tags: python, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call python script from Node.js. It is executing the python script but giving error in script  as  `ImportError:no module named google.cloud`
my Node.js has following code :

```
/**
 *  * Background Cloud Function to be triggered by Cloud Storage.
 *   *
 *    * @param {object} event The Cloud Functions event.
 *     * @param {function} callback The callback function.
 *      */
exports.hellogcspy1 = function (event, callback) {
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');


var options = {
  mode: 'text',
  pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python2.7',
  pythonOptions: ['-u'],
  scriptPath: '.',
  args: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
};
PythonShell.run('my_script.py', options, function (err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('results: %j', results);
});
};
```

python script is named as my_script.py . when I run this script from the directory where python-shell and package.json is created, I dont get any import error.
Package.json has following code :

```
{
  "name": "python-shell",
  "version": "0.4.0",
  "description": "to test python run",
  "main": "Node.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "python my_script.py"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "python"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "python-shell": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "repository": {},
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

my_script.py contains import of google-cloud modules i.e.

```
from google.cloud import storage,from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery import SchemaField
```

Its running fine on VM but not on Node.js. Can anyone please help why I am getting the error `ImportError:no module named google.cloud` when executed from Node.js ?

Comment: do you use the latest version of python google cloud? Try version google-cloud==0.27.0, the previous has some broken dependencies

Comment: are you suggesting to install this version of google-cloud? I ran $pip show google-cloud and got this: pip show google-cloud
Name: google-cloud
Version: 0.27.0
Summary: API Client library for Google Cloud
Home-page: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python
Author: Google Cloud Platform
Author-email: googleapis-publisher@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: google-cloud-translate, google-cloud-resource-manager, google-cloud-dns, google-cloud-bigquery, ....... It looks like it is latest version only.

Comment: When you run the script from the directory where python-shell and package.json is created, do you use python 2.7 or 3.x?

Comment: It is python2.7 as when i run script it goes to the path /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage....

Comment: what happens when you open live interpreter for `/usr/bin/python2.7` and you try to `import google.cloud`?

Comment: It looks ok from there. [deepshikha_patel@instance-1 test2]$ /usr/bin/python2.7
Python 2.7.5 (default, May  3 2017, 07:55:04) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-14)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from google.cloud import bigquery
>>> from google.cloud import storage
>>> from google.cloud.bigquery import SchemaField
>>>

Comment: Awaiting help on this 

Comment: Hi..any further help on this?